# .db file not found Flask SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

After executing the code, the database file (here test.db) is not found in the working directory or the home directory. The Python-flask code is given below. I have seen in the YouTube videos that the .db file is automatically created after the connection is successfully made.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'}


app = Flask(__name__)
#db_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.db')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///test.db' #path of the database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
#initialising the database
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
db.init_app(app)

#create database model
#we will not have to give sql commands, just can be created using class
class exec_members(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)   #person id
    name=db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False)    #execom member name
    postn=db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)  #position represented by the execom member
    twitter=db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)    #twitter id of the execom member
    facebook=db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)   #facebook id of the execom member
    instagram=db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)  ##instagram id of the execom member
    linkedin=db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)   #linkedin id of the execom member
    #img_name=db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)   #image of the execom member

@app.route("/admin")
def hello_world():
    return render_template('admin.html')


@app.route("/",methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route("/details",methods=['POST'])
def details():
    pname=request.form['name']
    post=request.form['post-name']
    twitterid=request.form['twitter']
    facebookid=request.form['facebook']
    instagramid=request.form['instagram']
    linkedinid=request.form['linkedin']
    try:
        db.session.add(exec_members(name=pname))
        db.session.add(exec_members(postn=post))
        db.session.add(exec_members(twitter=twitterid))
        db.session.add(exec_members(facebook=facebookid))
        db.session.add(exec_members(instagram=instagramid))
        db.session.add(exec_members(linkedin=linkedinid))
    except:
        print("Error adding to database!")
        return redirect('/admin')
#########################error uploading files to the database
    #print(name, post, twitter, facebook, instagram, linkedin)
```

Plus, there is no error returned after executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

No, the flask-sqlalchemy will not create a database itself. You should create it yourself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create the path to the directory you want the database file to be located:

```py
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) 
# this will be the top-level directory
```

Add your database configurations:

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'test.db')
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

If the `DATABASE_URL` variable is not found in the environment, then a file called `test.db` will be created in the top level directory.

When you run your migrations, then the `test.db` file will be automatically created, as you have 'heard'.